Mongo How to get only available documents by date
I have documents that associated to students:
[
{
'_id': 1,
'name': 'Anna',
'vacation_start: '2024-01-01',
'vacation_end': '2024-01-03'
},
{
'_id': 2,
'name': 'Bob',
'vacation_start: '2024-01-01',
'vacation_end': '2024-01-05'
},
{
'_id': 3,
'name': 'Zenna',
'vacation_start: '2024-02-02',
'vacation_end': '2024-02-10'
}
]

How can i get students that only available from my input to my input?
For example my input: available_from=2024-01-04 available_to=2024-02-02
And i want to get only Anna in this filters.
I was thinking about $gt and $lt but i do not think that this is the right way

Could you elaborate on "I was thinking about $gt and $lt but I do not think that this is the right way". From the description it seems to be exactly the way. What are you concerns to reject it?

Oh, you right i just overthink myself i guess. $lte and $gte will work here good

You can use $gte and $lt operators to filter a record between specific criteria
Example -
db.CollectionName.find({"whenCreated": {
    '$gte': ISODate("2018-03-06T13:10:40.294Z"),
    '$lt': ISODate("2018-05-06T13:10:40.294Z")
}});

Reference - https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-can-i-match-all-data-between-two-date/189642

I think it is a bad idea to compare a string values with a Date object. Either compare strings or Date objects.
